# why this code giving error mismatch in strcpy

Tags: c++

There is a mismatch error in `strcpy()` function. I'm new to the C++ language.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

#define max 5

class ss {
private:
    char str[max][10];
public:
    void  get_str() {
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            cin >> str[i];
    }
    void disp() {
        cout << "Entered strings are\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (strcmp(str[i], str[i + 1]) != 0)
                cout << str[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    /*
    void sort()
    {
        char temp[max];

        for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < (max - i - 1); j++)
            {
                if (strcmp(str[j], str[j + 1])>0)
                {
                    strcpy(temp, str[j]);
                    strcpy(str[j], str[j + 1]);
                    strcpy(str[j + 1], temp);
                }
            }
        disp();
    }
    */
    void qsort()
    {
        qs(str, 0, max - 1);
        disp();
    }
    void qs(char *&str, int st, int e)
    {
        int pi = part(str, st, e);
        qs(s, st, pi - 1);
        qs(s, pi + 1, e);
    }
    int part(char *&s, int st, int e)
    {
        char pi[max], swap[max];
        strcpy(pi, s[e]);
        int pii = st;
        int i = st;
        for (i; i < e; i++) {
            if ((strcmp(s[i], s[pii])) <= 0)
            {
                strcpy(swap, s[pii]);
                strcpy(s[pii], s[i]);
                strcpy(s[i], swap);
                pii++;
            }
        }
        strcpy(swap, str[e]);
        strcpy(str[e], str[pii]);
        strcpy(str[pii], swap);
    }
};

main()
{
    ss s;
    cout << "Enter the strings\n";
    s.get_str();
    s.disp();
    s.sort();
    cout << "after the sort" << endl;
    s.disp();
}
```

Comment: Which one? You have lots of `strcpy()`s in your code.

Comment: Fix the formatting. Fix the indentation. Provide the exact error message and show which line it is on.

Comment: all strcpy within " part()" definition .
its working fine without  function qs(). sorry Dark, i'll fix formating and come back with proper question.  thank you

Comment: @SPraveen - I think you meant `char **` for arguments to `qs()` and `part()`, not `char *&`.

Comment: To us here it is not very important that you are new to C++. You still have to reduce the code that you show us to be the [most minimal code that exhibits the problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @urfusion: Your formatting edit is terrible. Is this really the best you could do?

Comment: thanks to all for your reply. i dont want to waste your time on this question, first i'll try to learn how to fix formatting and some more practice on the C++. than you for suggestions.

Comment: @Blastfurnace my editor not support C and C++. So I did that manually. i didn't give a proper attention for formatting just make code a bit more easy to read.

Comment: @urfusion: Please take more care in the future. I personally wouldn't have approved the edit and think you can do better.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I will, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several problems with your code:

1. Arguments are passed to `qs()` and `part()` as `char *&`, not `char **` or `char [max][10]`.
2. `s` is undefined in `qs()` (did you mean `str`?).
3. ISO C++ forbids a definition of `main()` without a return value.
4. `part()` has a non-void return type and doesn't return a value.

Repaired code is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#define max 5
class ss {
    private:
        char str[max][10];
    public:
        void  get_str() {
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                cin >> str[i];
        }
        void disp() {
            cout << "Entered strings are\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (strcmp(str[i], str[i + 1]) != 0)
                cout << str[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    void sort()
    {
        char temp[max];

        for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < (max - i - 1); j++)
            {
                if (strcmp(str[j], str[j + 1])>0)
                {
                    strcpy(temp, str[j]);
                    strcpy(str[j], str[j + 1]);
                    strcpy(str[j + 1], temp);
                }
            }
        disp();
    }

    void qsort()
    {
        qs(reinterpret_cast<char **>(str), 0, max - 1);
        disp();
    }

    void qs(char **str, int st, int e)
    {
        int pi = part(reinterpret_cast<char **>(str), st, e);
        qs(str, st, pi - 1);
        qs(str, pi + 1, e);
    }

    int part(char **s, int st, int e)
    {
        char pi[max], swap[max];
        strcpy(pi, s[e]);
        int pii = st;
        int i = st;
        for (; i < e; i++) {
            if ((strcmp(s[i], s[pii])) <= 0)
            {
                strcpy(swap, s[pii]);
                strcpy(s[pii], s[i]);
                strcpy(s[i], swap);
                pii++;
            }
        }
        strcpy(swap, str[e]);
        strcpy(str[e], str[pii]);
        strcpy(str[pii], swap);
        // NO RETURN VALUE?
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ss s;
    cout << "Enter the strings\n";
    s.get_str();
    s.disp();
    s.sort();
    cout << "after the sort" << endl;
    s.disp();
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use `reinterpret_cast<>()`, you can use this:

```
...
void qsort()
{
    qs(str, 0, max - 1);
    disp();
}

void qs(char str[max][10], int st, int e)
{
    int pi = part(str, st, e);
    qs(str, st, pi - 1);
    qs(str, pi + 1, e);
}

int part(char s[max][10], int st, int e)
...
```